# Proper method of returning without completion from async function when an await promise rejects?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Would you please tell me the proper way to terminate an async function when an await promise fails/rejects?

In the code below, when promise `getValue()` rejects, the code at the end still attempts to run and do something with `r`.  At least that is what the error appears to state.  The `catch` on `getValue()` runs and then the `catch` of the `try` states that the function errored because `r` is `undefined` at a line in the "do something with r" section that follows.

Why doesn't the function stop at return or reject(), and how do I get it to stop after `getValue()` fails?

I realize that async/await works with try/catch such that errors will be caught as if synchronous; but I'd like to do something specific for each await failure and stop and return at that point.

Thank you.

```
async function afunc() {
 try {
   var r = await getValue().catch( (err) => {
              console.log( "Error in getValue" ); 
              console.log(err);
              r = "error";
              return;
           } );

    if ( r === "error" ) reject();
    /* do something with r */
  }
catch ( e )
 {
   console.log( "error in afunc" );
   console.log( e );
 }    
}
```

Comment: "*Why doesn't the function stop at return or reject()*" because the `return` is not in `afunc`, so it doesn't terminate `afunc`. The `reject` also doesn't stop the function by itself. Normally what you should do is very, very simple - you shouldn't have `.catch()` as that turns the rejection into normal completion. It's an error handling mechanism However, you've mixed `async`/`await` with the promise API which makes it odd. Moreover, you have a `reject()` indicating you're also manually trying to reject a promise. You shouldn't mix any two of these three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reject the promise fron an `async` function, you throw an error or allow one to be thrown.

Generally, don't use the `.then` and `.catch` methods directly. `await` is how you consume promises in `async` functions (by and large). Your code is catching the rejection (by using `.catch`) and converting it to a fulfillment with the value `undefined` (by not returning anything else from the rejection handler function).

But with `async` functions and `await`, rejections become errors and fulfillments become result values. So by doing `await getValue`, you're saying "If the `getValue` promise is rejected, `throw` that rejection; if `getValue` is fulfilled, get that fulfillment value." Similarly, `throw` in an `async` function turns into rejecting the promise the `async` function returns, and `return` turns into fulfilling it.

So just use the promise via `await` and allow the error (rejection) to propagate to the caller:

```
async function afunc() {
    var r = await getValue; // Slightly odd this is an identifier reference, not a function call

    /* do something with r */
}
```

Or if you need to do something with the rejection before propagating it:

```
async function afunc() {
    try {
        var r = await getValue; //

        /* do something with r */
    } catch (e) {
        /* do something with `e`, then rethrow it */
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I cover this in detail in Chapters 8 and 9 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: Thank you.  I was being rather stupid again and treating JS functions like void C functions. If I just `return "error"` and check for it afterward, it'll work.  I meant to have the `()` for a function invocation.

Comment: @Gary - But why do that, rather than using `try`/`catch`?

Comment: I don't know for sure except that there are a number of `await` statements in the function; but I suppose a `try/catch` for each `await` and an outer one over the entire function would be just as good.  And perhaps it seems a bit odd to handle the error on an await and then throw it again.  But I'm just a novice so that might be the best practice; I don't know. The primary point of my comment was that I now see why `return` without a value was not stopping the function execution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you are passing the value: "error" to a variable r within a variable r.
To return "error" you must return this value in the parent variable to be able to check.

```
async function afunc() {
 try {
   var r = await getValue.catch( (err) => {
              console.log( "Error in getValue" ); 
              console.log(err);
              var result = "error";
              return result;
           } );

    if ( r === "error" ) reject();
    /* do something with r */
  }
catch ( e )
 {
   console.log( "error in afunc" );
   console.log( e );
 }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I understand now.  I chose Mr. Crowder's answer because it came in two minutes before yours.

Comment: No problem. Anything we are here.